# Driver disconnecting, WebDriverException: disconnected: not connected to DevTools using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape a website with Selenium and the code had been working just fine with the scrolling task, but not arriving at the bottom of the page as I needed. So I have worked on other details and have been running it over the past week, and the webdriver had been able to scroll for much longer on previous attempts. However, I have been getting this error now every time I run the code below, and the webdriver is disconnecting sooner with time at a smaller scroll height. I have tried deleting and installing again the driver, using Chrome, Chromium and Brave, and I am not closing the window or doing any activity on Chrome. I am working on a OS 13.2.1, with M2. I am using miniconda and Spyder to run it. My python version is 3.10.9. Can anyone help me to understand how to deal with this error?

This is part of the code I am running:

Install Browser

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=BraveService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.BRAVE).install()))
time.sleep(6)
```

Set URL to navigate to

```
url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Dunn's+Famous/@45.5005714,-73.5760788,17z/data=!3m2!4b1!5s0x4cc91a43938ac4ff:0x269f03725dd7f0b9!4m6!3m5!1s0x4cc91a43945e5f97:0xb06f7b6c79d571c9!8m2!3d45.5005715!4d-73.5715941!16s%2Fg%2F11b7f_ygcz"
```

Navigate to page

```
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div/div/button').click()
time.sleep(6)
```

Finding and clicking on review button to display reviews

```
divs = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div")
for div in divs:
    if div.get_attribute('role') == 'button' and re.search(r"[0-9]*[,][0-9]*\sreviews",div.text):
        try:
            div.click()
            break                
        except:
            pass
comment_number = 1
time.sleep(6)
```

Get scroll height

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

number = 0

while True:
    
    try:
        
        number+=1
```

Scroll down to bottom

```
comment = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 5000);', comment)

Wait to load page


  time.sleep(6)
```

Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height

```
print(f'last height: {last_height}')

    comment = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]')

    new_height = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", comment)

    print(f'new height: {new_height}')
    
    print('cont')
    last_height = new_height
```

scroll height that the scrolling freezes

```
 if last_height == 295356:
        break
    
except:
    break
```

**This is the error I get**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/xx.py:112
    reviews_divs = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[10]')

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:830 in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:440 in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/spyder-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:245 in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.177)
```

I have tried deleting and installing again the driver.

Comment: sounds like the page is crashing... (which can happen if too much content is loaded in... most sites use a sort of rolling cache of data to display to avoid this... top-offscreen items get removed from DOM on scroll, while new ones get added keeping the size of data displayed the same.)

Comment: I suggest you using `scrollIntoView` instead of `scrollBy`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix a similar issue by adding the following to my chrome_options:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

The --no-sandbox keeps chromedriver from running in a sandbox process and the --disable-dev-shm-usage forces chromedriver to use the /tmp directory instead of /dev/shm because sometimes that can be too small for the website you are accessing.

Hopefully this will help resolve your issue.